# Uniform initialization of an atomic struct?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, uniform-initialization, aggregate-initialization

```
struct S
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

std::atomic<S> asd{{1, 2}}; // what should this be? This doesn't work
```

Edit: Both `{{1, 2}}` and `({1, 2})` work in g++, neither work in clang. Is there a workaround for clang?

Comment: I don't see any hack; one cannot even later manually assign an S to that beast. But let's think positive - it is not "just" by the standard but  manifestly thread-safe that way... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [clang bug 18097](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18097). [Here's](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.clang.devel/29496) a long thread discussing the issue, which seems to be that clang only supports scalar types for `T` in `atomic<T>`. The C++11 standard clearly states (§29.5/1) that `T` can be any trivially copyable type.

Both the usages shown in the question should match this constructor

```
constexpr atomic(T) noexcept;
```

The only way I can think of working around this is to default construct `atomic<S>` and then use `atomic::store` to initialize the object.

```
std::atomic<S> asd;
asd.store({1,2});
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::atomic<S> asd({1, 2});`

`std::atomic<S>` has a constructor which takes a value of type S.
The initializer list {1, 2} is implicitly converted to a temporary S because of this constructor.

Comment: @axnsan Can you explain why the uniform initialization doesn't work? It should work in my opinion.

Comment: this doesn't compile on `clang++` either. Both versions however compile on `g++`

Comment: @vsoftco Ya, that's the issue I'm having... using clang. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Yes, apparently I was wrong and your first version should also compile. My version works for me in MSVC 2013, however the first one doesn't. It's probably a bug in the compiler.

As a workaround try `std::atomic<S> asd(S{1,2});`. What version of clang are you using, by the way?

Comment: @axnsan: The symptom remains, however you twist it; there plainly is (/usr/include/c++/v1/atomic:632:58: error:) no viable conversion from 'S' to '_Atomic(S)'